# How to set minimumfont size or minimumscalfactor(ios7) with the attributed string?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

How to set minimumfont size or minimumscalfactor(ios7) with the attributed string.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
   paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment;

    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ NSFontAttributeName: self.font,
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName:self.textColor};


    [self.formattedText drawAtPoint:vLineRect.origin withAttributes:dictionary];
```

Please suggest how can i set minimumfont size in attributed string?

Answer (score 3):

To replace `minimumFontSize` you need to use `minimumScaleFactor` with iOS 7 like this :

```
[_myLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:10.0/FONT]];
```

*10.0 will be the minimum size*.

And replace FONT by your custom font with the size ( `[UIFont fontWithName:@"nameOfFont" size:15.0f]`, with the name of your font and the size you want ).

So with iOS 6 it would be the same as :

```
[_myLabel setMinimumFontSize:10.0];
```

Apple Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html).

You can add a test to use `minimumFontSize` with iOS 6 and `minimumScaleFactor` with iOS 7 :

```
if ([_myLabel respondsToSelector:@selector(setMinimumScaleFactor:)])
    [_myLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:10.0/FONT]];
else
    [_myLabel setMinimumFontSize:10.0];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i want to set mininumscalfactor in attributed string.How can i achieve this. I want print text using drawAtPoint:withattribute.

Comment: You are going to put your text in a textview or a label. So you can setMinimumScaleFactor to your label and not on your NSAttributedString.

Comment: This is wrong: [_myLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:10.0/FONT]]; You should use [_myLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:10.0/font size]]; e.g. : [_myLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:10.0/25.0]]; 25.0 is the size of your original FONT size. And 10.0 is the minimum you want. That means a value of 0.4. That is the value that Apple needs.

Comment: i think font should be a value - a number not an object as you described above